# Get React dom components from children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I figure out how to retrieve children of a React component via `this.props.children` and its accessor addon `React.children`. But all I get are instances of `ReactElement`.

Once my parent component and children are mounted, how can I get objects having the method `getDOMNode` (i.e. instances of `ReactDOMComponent`) ?

I still work with React 0.12. I know...

Comment: Once the components are mounted, they're in the DOM ... so you can just use standard DOM methods from a root node. Children of a React component are `ReactElement`s, so that's behaving as expected. So, what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score -1):

You can get them as you normally would - by selecting them with jQuery or document.querySelectorAll. They are just DOM nodes after all.